# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use following SQL statement but as soon as fire the query i am getting **'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.**' error message.

i have tried converting fiscalperiod as well as dates in where clause to valid datetime but as soon as i use filter for datetime query fails.

If i store the same result in temp table and then use date filters on the temp table then i get the expected results.

Can you please check what wrong in below query?

```
WITH TEMP_LEDGERPERIOD ( DATAAREAID, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND, FISCALPERIOD )
AS 
(
    SELECT dataareaid, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-' + COMMENTARIES) AS FiscalPeriod
    FROM LEDGERPERIOD LPT WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (COMMENTARIES NOT LIKE '%OPEN' and COMMENTARIES NOT LIKE '%CLOSE')
)

Select * 
from TEMP_LEDGERPERIOD
where FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/02/01'
```

Comment: What does `commentaries` look like?

Comment: is error on WHERE clause, or on CONVERT function? comment out WHERE clause to see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

When using dates, you should either use ISO standard date formats or be explicit about conversions.  I have no idea what `COMMENTARIES` looks like, but "01-" at the beginning of a date seems an unlikely format.

In addition, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, unless you use a `CASE`.  So, the filtering in the `WHERE` clause may take place *after* the calculation of the new value.  Fortunately, SQL Server 2012+ offers `TRY_CONVERT()`.

If I assume the format of `COMMENTARIES` is "YYYY-MM", then you can go for:

```
WITH TEMP_LEDGERPERIOD ( DATAAREAID, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND, FISCALPERIOD ) AS (
      SELECT dataareaid, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND,
             TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, COMMENTARIES + '-01') AS FiscalPeriod
      FROM LEDGERPERIOD LPT WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE COMMENTARIES NOT LIKE '%OPEN' and COMMENTARIES NOT LIKE '%CLOSE'
     )
Select * 
from TEMP_LEDGERPERIOD
where FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01';
```

Finally, do you realize that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so this includes the first day of February.

Comment: One format I can think of that would make sense to prepend `'01-'` to is `MMM-YY` like `JAN-16`.  Granted there are probably _safer_ ways to convert but it should work,